# Getting future warning in panda, equivalent function in python datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting Future warning message, FutureWarning: The pandas.datetime class is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import from datetime module instead.

The warning message is generated for the code line,

```
quarter_ends = pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.today()) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()
```

The warning says to import from datetime module. Any inbuilt function in datetime to find the end of current quarter?

Comment: Just a guess, but `pd.offsets.QuarterEnd` is probably fine as is, only the `pd.datetime` should be changed…?

Comment: But, when I ran, this `quarter_ends = pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.today()) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()` didn't generate the warning.